# Format template string to remove whitespace but support indentation

Tags: javascript

Say I have the following template string:

```
const str1 = ` 
        const x = 5;
`
```

If I were to render it in the DOM it would take into consideration the whitespace before the string begins and render it with the whitespace. I could solve this using `str1.trim()`, but, lets say we have another string:

```
const str2 = `
        const x = 1;
          const y = 2;
            const z = 3;
`
```

I would like to remove the whitespace before each string row but preserve the indentation. An expected result would look something like:

```
const x = 1;
  const y = 2;
    const z = 3;
```

Is there a way I could achieve this with either regex or js ?

Comment: There are too many ways to approach this problem. The answers would just turn into a straw-poll for which one people liked. The best thing is to do some research on the topic yourself, find two or three, _analyze_ them, determine if they work for you or not, and _try them out_. Come to us when you have a specific question about something you have attempted to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure out the number of space characters between the first newline and the first real character, then remove that number of space characters from the beginning of each row and trim:

```js
const str2 = `
        const x = 1;
          const y = 2;
            const z = 3;
`;
const numSpaces = str2.match(/\n +/)[0].length;
const result = str2
  .replace(new RegExp(`\\n {${numSpaces}}`, 'g'), '\n')
  .trim();
console.log(result);
```

Or, if you need to iterate through *all* lines beforehand to figure out which has the least indentation:

```js
const str2 = `
            const x = 1;
          const y = 2;
            const z = 3;
`;
const numSpaces = str2.match(/\n +/g).reduce((a, b) => Math.min(a, b.length - 1), Infinity);
console.log(numSpaces);
const result = str2
  .replace(new RegExp(`\\n {${numSpaces}}`, 'g'), '\n')
  .replace(/^ *$\n/g, '');
console.log(result);
```